# Streaming MSSQL CDC to AWS MSK with Debezium

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, debezium, aws-msk

I'm a newbie with Kafka and currently learning to streaming data changed from MSSQL to Amazon MSK using Debezium connector

I already have a MS SQL Server with CDC enabled, a MSK cluster which I can connect, create topic, produce and consume data manually through an EC2 client. Now I'm setting up a MSK Connect with Debezium SQL Server connector as custom plugin, here is my MSK Connector configurations:

```
connector.class = io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector, 
tasks.max = 1
database.hostname = xxx, 
database.port = xxx, 
database.user = xxx, 
database.password = xxx, 
database.dbname = dbName, 
database.server.name = serverName, 
table.include.list = dbo.tableName, 
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers = xxx, 
database.history.kafka.topic = xxx
```

But my MSK connector keeps returning status Failed. I have searched Google though but it seems there is no instruction or guide related to my idea.

That makes me wondering whether my solution is possible? Could someone please shed some light and point me to the right direction?

Edited: some logs I got from CloudWatch

```
ERROR [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -2 () failed authentication due to: []: Access denied (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:771)

INFO App info kafka.admin.client for adminclient-1 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:83)

[INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Metadata update failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager:235)

org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster. Check worker's broker connection and security properties.

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: [4f91d358-fb7b-4f3b-8930-1b4aefce6d0b]: Access denied

[Worker-08134a52fe88cdc49] MSK Connect encountered errors and failed.
```

Many thanks,

Comment: Do the logs tell you why it's failed?

Comment: Some logs say about SaslAuthenticationException and Failed to connect to and describe Kafka cluster. Could it be my msk connector's role not have sufficient permissions? Or maybe my sqlserver connection is inccorect? I'm using public ip4 with port 1433, I have updated some logs in my post

Comment: I don't use MSK, but if there are SASL or SSL listeners that you're connecting to, then you need Debezium to define JAAS or SSL properties as well

Comment: How was the issue resolved?

Comment: I'm hitting the same problem - how was the issue resolved? @liv

Comment: @YichaoZhao
Sorry for not keeping the issue updated, it turned out we are using IAM role base so the connector need an execution role.
I've created a new IAM role follow instruction here and attached to the connector and it worked: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-connect-service-execution-role.html

Comment: @RajSaraogi I've updated the answer above, you can take a look

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IAM role based auth for your MSK cluster, your bootstrap server port will be `9098`

Along with all the properties, you also have send these properties in your MSK connect config

```
database.history.consumer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
database.history.consumer.sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM
database.history.consumer.sasl.jaas.config=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
database.history.consumer.sasl.client.callback.handler.class=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
database.history.producer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
database.history.producer.sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM
database.history.producer.sasl.jaas.config=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
database.history.producer.sasl.client.callback.handler.class=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
```

Refer: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-amazon-msk-connect-stream-data-to-and-from-your-apache-kafka-clusters-using-managed-connectors/