# AWS MSK Connect w/ MSSQL Debezium connector fails with disconnect

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, aws-msk

I am trying to setup a mssql debezium connector with AWS MSK Connect but keep getting the following error messages:

Connector error log:

> [Worker-0a949760f6b805d4f] [2023-02-15 19:57:56,122] WARN [src-connector-014|task-0] [Consumer clientId=dlp.compcare.ccdemo-schemahistory, groupId=dlp.compcare.ccdemo-schemahistory] Bootstrap broker b-3.stuff.morestuff.c7.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9098 (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1079)

This error happens continuously for a bit then I see this error:

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata

In the cluster logs I see a corresponding error when I get the disconnect error:

> [2023-02-15 20:08:21,627] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=3] Failed authentication with /172.32.34.126 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)

I have an ec2 client that i've setup to connect to my cluster and am able to connect and run commands against the cluster using IAM auth. I have setup a topic and produced and consumed from the topic using the console producer/consumers. I've also verified that when the connector start up it is creating the `__amazon_msk_connect_status_*` and `__amazon_msk_connect_offsets_*` topics.

I've verified that ip in the logs is the ip assigned to my connector by checking the Elastic Network Interface it was attached to.

Also for testing purposes I've opened up all traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 for the SG they are running in and also made sure the IAM role has msk*, msk-connect*, kafka*, and s3*.

I've also verified CDC is enabled on the RDS and that it is working properly. I see changes being picked and added to the CDC tables.

I believe the issue is related to IAM auth still but am not certain.
Cluster Config:

```
auto.create.topics.enable=true
delete.topic.enable=true
```

worker config:

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
config.providers.secretManager.class=com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.config.aws.SecretsManagerConfigProvider
config.providers=secretManager
config.providers.secretManager.param.aws.region=us-east-1
request.timeout.ms=90000
errors.log.enable=true
errors.log.include.messages=true
```

Connector Config:

```
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector
tasks.max=1
database.history.consumer.sasl.jaas.config=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
schema.include.list=dbo
database.history.producer.sasl.client.callback.handler.class=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
database.history.consumer.sasl.client.callback.handler.class=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
database.history.consumer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
database.instance=MSSQLSERVER
topic.prefix=dlp.compcare.ccdemo
schema.history.internal.kafka.topic=dlp.compcare.ccdemo.history
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
database.history.sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM
database.encrypt=false
database.history.sasl.jaas.config=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
database.history.producer.sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM
database.history.producer.sasl.jaas.config=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
database.user=debezium
database.names=Intermodal_CCDEMO
database.history.producer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
database.server.name=ccdemo_1
schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers=b-1:9098
database.port=1433
database.hostname=my-mssql-rds.rds.amazonaws.com
database.history.sasl.client.callback.handler.class=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
database.password=${secretManager:dlp-compcare:dbpassword}
table.include.list=dbo.EquipmentSetup
database.history.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
database.history.consumer.sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM
```

I was able to do this same process but with a postgres rds with no issues.

I've tried everything I can think of so any an all help would be greatly appreciated!

I also referenced the following when setting up the cluster/connector:

- https://catalog.workshops.aws/msk-labs/en-US/mskconnect/source-connector-setup
- https://thedataguy.in/debezium-with-aws-msk-iam-authentication/
- https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/sqlserver.html#sqlserver-connector-properties
- [Streaming MSSQL CDC to AWS MSK with Debezium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69853216/streaming-mssql-cdc-to-aws-msk-with-debezium)
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/mkc-debeziumsource-connector-example.html

Comment: You need to configure TLS on Debezium's SQL Server Connector. Otherwise, TLS handshakes will continue to fail. Look into the trust store properties.

Comment: @Rafael Can you elaborate? I am using IAM auth so from what I've read I don't believe I need to configure TLS properties. I've also been able to connect and produce/consume from an EC2 client I configured with IAM auth with no issues. Also in the AWS docs for IAM auth it states: "If you don't want to use a specific certificate, you can remove ssl.truststore.location=<PATH_TO_TRUST_STORE_FILE> from your client.properties file. When you don't specify a value for ssl.truststore.location, the Java process uses the default certificate." found here:

Comment: What phase in the TLS handshake process is it failing, waiting on ServerHello? If so, it could be a remote connectivity issue.

Comment: This is probably about server certificates, not client certificates. SQL Server instances are installed with a self-signed certificate by default (i.e.: untrusted), although AWS RDS instances have one whose subject matches the instance's domain name. You'll probably need to download the public key for your RDS instance and import it into your Java trust store. Start with [Using SSL with a Microsoft SQL Server DB instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Concepts.General.SSL.Using.html), but you'll have to modify the import instructions to suit Java.

Comment: I don't think that's possible I'm using managed MSK Connect. I have no control over the instance it provisions and I can't change any of the ssl or sasl properties on the worker per the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-connect-workers.html. I do agree that I think it's a issue with SSL connection to the RDS though. I can't even find where the default cacert is located on the instance.

Comment: @EthanDavis out of trial and error, can you try to change `database.encrypt=true` and check will it make any difference?

Comment: @KarimTawfik I tried like you suggested but the connector requires the following additional configs:   `database.ssl.truststore: path/to/trust-store`
        `database.ssl.truststore.password: password-for-trust-store`, and since I'm using managed MSK connect I don't know the location to the trust store I've tried several different paths with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a ton of digging and some help from an AWS support rep I finally figure out my issue. It was related to IAM authentication. This property

`schema.history.internal.kafka.topic`

Requires you to specify how to authenticate to create the topics for schema history etc.

In order to do that you need to add the following properties to your connector

```
schema.history.internal.consumer.sasl.client.callback.handler.class=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
schema.history.internal.consumer.sasl.jaas.config=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
schema.history.internal.consumer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
schema.history.internal.consumer.sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM

schema.history.internal.producer.sasl.client.callback.handler.class=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
schema.history.internal.producer.sasl.jaas.config=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;
schema.history.internal.producer.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
schema.history.internal.producer.sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM
```

I tested this for SQL Server and MySql and it worked for me.

Comment: Can i see the full list of your mysql connector configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing the same issue when connecting to the Aurora MYSQL DB.

I was using the latest version of Debezium [v2.1.2](https://debezium.io/releases/2.1/#installation)

However, with the same setup when I used the previous version [v1.7.0](https://debezium.io/releases/1.7/#installation), it worked just fine.

I have noticed version [v1.7.0](https://debezium.io/releases/1.7/#installation) accepts the following parameters:

```
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=<masked>
database.history.kafka.topic=<masked>
```

Can be seen in the Mysql example for v1.7 [here](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.7/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-example-configuration).

But the latest version complains about the above two and request a new parameter called `topic.prefix`:

```
schema.history.internal.kafka.topic=<masked>
schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers=<masked>
topic.prefix=<masked>
```

Which can be seen in the Mysql example for v2.1 [here](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/2.1/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-example-configuration).

To summarize, even after fixing the configurations changes, it works on v1.7, but doesn't on v2.1.2. This would mean, either it's a bug or we are missing some additional configurations.

I will keep you posted if I am able to figure it out.

In the meantime, can you try with a previous version too?

Comment: Yeah I'll try with 1.7 and see what happens and let you know

Comment: Yeah 1.7 doesn't work for me

Comment: To Reviewers: "Still no answer to the question, and you have the same problem? Help us find a solution by researching the problem, then contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a partial answer. That way, even if we can’t figure it out, the next person has more to go on." (from [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)).